# Where is the Council Tax rebate being funded from?

Tags: united-kingdom, public-funding

The UK government is legislating for a [Council Tax](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/52022-council-tax-information-letter-24-february-2022/council-tax-energy-rebate-information-leaflet-for-households-in-council-tax-bands-a-d) rebate to help with the cost of living crisis.

Where is the £3.3bn required to fund the rebate coming from? General taxation or council budgets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scheme is being funded from general taxation - see the Chancellor, Rishi Sunak’s [comments](https://hansard.parliament.uk/Commons/2022-02-03/debates/C5CCE4F1-1C96-47FA-B57E-B2701F67A099/EconomicUpdate#contribution-91763FCC-FC03-4D6D-8746-37520009BD34) in response to Dame Meg Hillier in the Commons announcing the measure on February 3rd:

> **Dame Meg Hillier:** I see we now have the Klarna Chancellor—“Get it now, pay later.” There is an important issue with council tax: in areas such as mine and other parts of London, there are not many people in those bands, and certainly not in bands A to C. Who will fund the council tax rebate? Will it be fully funded by the Exchequer, and will there be a weighting of the £150 million fund to areas such as mine, where there are poor households in high-value properties?
>
> **Rishi Sunak:** Just to confirm for the hon. Lady, it is council tax bands A to D, so it is four out of every five households across England. Obviously, that will vary by region. **I can confirm that it will be fully Exchequer-funded** and, on top of that, there will be a discretionary fund of around £150 million, for which the Department for Levelling Up, Housing and Communities will decide the best allocation formula. Local authorities will be able to use that to help those low-income households that happen to live in higher council tax band properties and those people, such as students, who are exempt from paying council tax at all, but whom we would want to get that support to.

I would add that this scheme applies only to homes in England, although the devolved parliaments will receive additional funding in lieu of the scheme through the Barnett formula.